# How to Highlight or make a text file on HTML vscode

Tags: html, css

Hi im new to HTML here currently want to ask how to highlight a The code in vs code? example if we're on C++ we use //text// but how about on HTML? or perhaps i forgot the name of what's it called ? to highlight the text to make it disabled for running
example like in the picture : [image: Example of picture in circle] i want to make it into a text not a code just for Testing before im running. Thank you.

Comment: you write about HTML but show a CSS file, and you mention C++, very vague what you want

Comment: well tbh what i mean is either on HTML or at CSS what i mean is at vscode we use what command to mark code turn into text

Comment: still vague: code is text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so do you meaning comments???
if it is so you can use

```html
    <!--
    your code
    -->
```

or select your code in vscode and press
[cmd + /]

Comment: uhhhh, im on Windows so what command should i use ? Ctrl+/ ?

Comment: yep use ctrl + /

Comment: Usually cmd in mac works like ctrl in windows.   @Vincent Thamrin